# What is an analog of request.Properties in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In WebApi2 it was common to put arbitrary objects into `HttRequestMessage.Properties`. Usually it was doing with extension-methods like `request.SetUserRights()` where `SetUserRights` just put an object into `request.Properties[HttpPropertyKey.UserRights]`.

Now in ASP.NET 5 there is no such property in `HttpRequest`.

What pattern is supposed to be be used for passing arbitrary objects along with http request?

In WebApi for putting objects in request.Properties filters were used usually. We still have filters in AspNet5, so the question can be rephrased as: where should a filter put common data specific for the request.
Examples of such data can be: current user's roles, current user's language and so on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`HttpContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/e818783ba4b818542a681be4a206dc40804c33a6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpContext.cs) class has [`Items`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/e818783ba4b818542a681be4a206dc40804c33a6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/HttpContext.cs#L23) property which you can use for this purpose.

Comment: This can be accessed by `HttpRequest.Context.Items` from anywhere you have the `HttpRequest`.